# Animating constraint thru updateConstraints or viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I working on my project which was landscape only. Recently I have decided that I should introduce portray mode. 
and I started using as usual choice :

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size
       withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
```

I did put logic as 
if width > height //landscape mode
  //animate constraint code
else //portray mode

This was working good.
eventually working on this problem. I found out about :

```
-(void)updateViewConstraints  method
```

so I moved all the code to updateViewConstraints and everything was working as it was in viewWillTransitionToSize:
I know both are quite different stuff. Might be giving me the same result. I am not able to separate them out in my head. hence I am here. Can anybody tell me how they are are giving me same result. 
Should I keep my code in both of these methods or one. 
As I am trying to make this code perfect I dont want same sort of code in two places. It it would be double maintenance.

Consider below is the screen and all square brackets are the subviews that would animate when go landscape to portray. In landscape its 2 rows and 3 columns. when it would go to portray there would be 3 rows and 2 columns.

```
----------------------
|                    |
|  []     []    []   |
|  []     []    []   |
|                    |
|---------------------
```

Please feel free to edit. Comments are welcome if I am not able to present problem correctly. 
Thanks